# Reshape Dataframe based on conditions of other rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

Code to recreate above:

```
input_lst = [[27141, 0, 0, 2081.39, np.nan, np.nan, '31/05/2025', '31/03/2021'],
  [26142, 401.04, 1934.52, 0, np.nan, np.nan, '01/04/2021', '20/11/2009'],
  [27748, 0, 0, 266.09, np.nan, np.nan, '18/01/2011', '30/04/2005'],
  [26742, 0, 990.48, 0, np.nan, np.nan, '21/06/2011', '27/06/2008'],
  [27564, 0, 1173.24, 466.33, np.nan, np.nan, '10/06/2004', '31/12/2004']]
input_headers = ['Ref', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'Commence Date 1', 'Commence Date 2']
test_df = pd.DataFrame(input_lst, columns=input_headers)
```

I want to reshape the dataframe or something similar, so my resulting dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Code to view resulting dataframe:

```
res_lst = [[27141, 2081.39, 'GHI', '31/03/2021'],
[26142, 401.04, 'ABC', '01/04/2021'],
[26142, 1934.52, 'DEF', '01/04/2021'],
[27748, 266.09, 'GHI', '30/04/2005'],
[26742, 990.48, 'DEF', '21/06/2011'],
[27564, 1173.24, 'DEF', '10/06/2004'],
[27564, 466.33, 'GHI', '31/12/2004']]
res_headers = ['Ref', 'Amount', 'Type', 'Commence Date']
result_df = pd.DataFrame(res_lst, columns=res_headers)
```

For each 'Ref' row, there can be up to 5 columns (ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO) in the original dataframe. The figures held in those columns in the original dataframe will be output to a column called 'Amount', but the 'Type' column is essentially what is the corresponding header name for those amounts. These also need to have a 'Commence Date' based on a condition. If original 'Type' is in either what is held under ABC or DEF, the resulting dataframe should output what is in 'Commence Date 1', otherwise if it's GHI/JKL/MNO, it should use 'Commence Date 2'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: @gtomer, it's not pivot problem, but melt problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melt the dataframe with the required indices and values columns, then filter out the records with `NaN`, or `0` amount, then finally assign the Date values based on type:

```py
out = test_df.melt(['Ref', 'Commence Date 1', 'Commence Date 2'],
                   ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO'],
                   'Type',
                   'Amount')
out = out[~(pd.isna(out['Amount']) | out['Amount'].eq(0))]
out = (out.assign(**{
    'Commence Date': out.apply(lambda x: x['Commence Date 1']
    if x['Type'] in {'ABC', 'DEF'} else x['Commence Date 2'],
                               axis=1)})
       .drop(columns=['Commence Date 1', 'Commence Date 2'])
       )
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
      Ref Type   Amount Commence Date
1   26142  ABC   401.04    01/04/2021
6   26142  DEF  1934.52    01/04/2021
8   26742  DEF   990.48    21/06/2011
9   27564  DEF  1173.24    10/06/2004
10  27141  GHI  2081.39    31/03/2021
12  27748  GHI   266.09    30/04/2005
14  27564  GHI   466.33    31/12/2004
```

You can reset the index of resulting dataframe, sort the dataframe on `Ref` column based on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

`melt` is a good option; however, it might not be efficient, depending on the data size - you have rows that are 0 or nan, which you do not care about; melt returns all those rows, after which you then filter. A better option would be to avoid flipping to long form, and avoid the nulls. It is a longer process, but should be beneficial as the data size increases.

```py
# select the columns from ABC to MNO
arr = test_df.loc[:, 'ABC':'MNO']

# get the columns, we'll use that later
arr_cols = arr.columns

# get boolean output for rows greater than 0
arr = arr.to_numpy()
bools = arr > 0

# get row and col positions for True values
row, col = bools.nonzero()

# create the Ref series
ref = test_df.Ref.repeat(bools.sum(1))
ref.index = range(len(ref))

# get the Type series
types = arr_cols[col]
types = pd.Series(types, name = 'Type')

# get the Amount
amount = arr[row, col]
amount = pd.Series(amount, name = 'Amount')

# Extract the dates
dates = test_df.filter(like='Comm').to_numpy()

# generate index, we'll use the index
# in combination with `row` to get the matching dates
# ABC, DEF are 0 and 1
# hence the conditional below
ind = np.where(col < 2, 0, 1)
dates = dates[row, ind]
dates = pd.Series(dates, name = 'Commence Date')

# combine ref, types, amount, dates
out = pd.concat([ref, types, amount, dates], axis = 1)
out

     Ref Type   Amount Commence Date
0  27141  GHI  2081.39    31/03/2021
1  26142  ABC   401.04    01/04/2021
2  26142  DEF  1934.52    01/04/2021
3  27748  GHI   266.09    30/04/2005
4  26742  DEF   990.48    21/06/2011
5  27564  DEF  1173.24    10/06/2004
6  27564  GHI   466.33    31/12/2004
```

Again, you'd bother with this long process if you are looking for efficiency, otherwise the melt solution above does the job.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! As my file sizes will be relatively small-medium sized, I've gone for the melt method, although if the files were much bigger (at some point, the program I'm running could very well need to cater for larger files), this would be a very useful alternative. I very much appreciate the effort you've taken in responding and coming up with your solution. I've upvoted your response, thanks!